# TexStudio 4.3.1 doesn't recognize the keyboard

Tags: texstudio

I have installed (2 times) the last version (4.3.1) of TexStudio and I can't use my keyyboard, that works for all the others programs.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Maybe ask at https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues  (and maybe include your operating system and keyboard layout)

Comment: Thanks. No answer from the link. I use Windows 10 and I have an Italian keyboard.

Comment: Resolved! After uninstalled the program I have deleted manually every occurrence of texstudio.ini from my computer.